# How to open a raw image file in R?

Tags: r, image, raw

A raw image is made of raw data coming from the camera sensor alongside other data. I want to open the raw image and extract the raw sensor data in the form of a matrix. I know it's not an image, but I just want to access the raw values.

I tried to use

```
hexView:: readRaw()
```

but it seems to put the entire raw file (sensor raw data + eventual other data) into one vector (in hexadecimal) and I don't know where to start and where to end the sensor data.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431346/reading-and-converting-binary-raw-data-with-r

Comment: I checked it out, but he knew the structure of his file, and it was a csv one.

Comment: Identifying the camera you are using and sharing a sample raw file might help...